# Find the smallest prime divisor of $1^{60}+2^{60}+...+33^{60}$

Tags: number-theory, modular-arithmetic, primitive-roots

> Find the smallest prime divisor of $1^{60}+2^{60}+...+33^{60}$.

I found a solution online, but I have a few questions:

1. In the beginning, the solver claims that $S^n = \begin{cases}S &\text{if } (p-1)\nmid n,\\ \{1\}&\text{if } (p-1)\mid n\end{cases}$. Can he do this because $S^n \equiv S\mod n \text{ if } (p-1)\nmid n$ and $S^n\equiv 1\mod n \text{ if } (p-1)\mid n$? $n$ does not need to be prime, so how does this follow from Fermat's Little Theorem? Apparently this claim is **wrong**.
2. I don't get why $\sum_{n}$ is divisible by $n$ if $(p-1)\nmid n$ and equivalent to $-1\mod n$ otherwise. I guess I can sort of understand why it could be a multiple of $n$, but why does that depend on whether $(p-1)\mid n$?
3. Why was the solver able to claim that $T_{k,n}=q\sum_{n}+1^n+2^n+\dots+r^n=\begin{cases}1^n+2^n+\dots+r^n &\text{ if } (p-1)\nmid n\\ r-q &\text { if } (p-1)\mid n\end{cases}$? The first case I understand because if $(p-1)\nmid n$, then $\sum_{n}\equiv 0\mod n$. And as for the second case, I know he uses the fact that if $(p-1)\mid n,\text { then } \sum_{n}\equiv -1\mod n$.

Everything else I understand.

> [image: A solution to the problem above]

Comment: Ad 1: It is not impossible to claim wrong things. I suppose you will agree that $(5 - 1) \nmid 2$. Now, with $p = 5$ and $n = 2$, look at $S = \{1,2,3,4\}$ and $S^2$, the latter reduces to $\{1,4\}$ (modulo $5$), thus $S^2 \neq S$.

Comment: Hmm. so it is wrong. It didn't even follow Fermat's Little Theorem as I pointed out, so I was considering the possibility that it was wrong. But, clearly, that incorrect claim does not lead to an incorrect answer, so the rest of the claims are most likely true.

Comment: What one needs is $$\sum_{k = 1}^{p-1} k^n \equiv \begin{cases} 0 \pmod{p} & \text{if } (p-1) \nmid n, \\ -1 \pmod{p} &\text{if } (p-1) \mid n. \end{cases}$$

Comment: Do you know about primitive roots modulo primes?

Comment: Yes. There always are primitive roots modulo primes. Let $p$ be a prime, and $g$ a primitive root modulo $p$. Then $$\sum_{k = 1}^{p-1} k^n = \sum_{j = 0}^{p-2} \bigl(g^j\bigr)^n = \sum_{j = 0}^{p-2} \bigl(g^n\bigr)^j.$$ Now use the formula for a geometric sum, and note for which $n$ we have $g^n \equiv 1 \pmod{p}$.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Note that the solution is much more complicated than it needs.

First note that for $p \in \{ 2, 3, 5, 7, 11, 13 \}$ since $p-1|60$ you have
$$x^{60} = \left\{
\begin{array}{lc}
1 & \mbox{ if  } p \nmid x \\
0 & \mbox{ if  } p \mid x \\
\end{array}
\right.$$

Using this, it is easy to show that no prime in the set $ \{ 2, 3, 5, 7, 11, 13 \}$ divides your sum.

**Next**, for $p=17$, let 
$$S=1^{60}+2^{60}+…+33^{60}$$

Note that for each $a \in \{ 1, 2, 3,.., 16 \} \pmod{17}$ the function $x \to ax$ is a permutation of the numbers $1,2,3,...,33 \pmod{17}$.

From here it is easy to deduce that 
$$S=a^{60}S \pmod{17}$$

If you can find an $a \neq 0$ such that $a^{60} \neq 1 \pmod{17}$ (which you can argue theoretically that it exists via primitive roots, but you can find very fast by test and error) you can deduce from here that $S \equiv 0 \pmod{17}$.

**P.S.** Note here that $gcd(60, 17-1)=4$. Aince $a^{16}=1 \pmod{17}$ for all $ \neq 0$, you get immediately that $$a^{60} \equiv 1 \pmod{17} \Leftrightarrow a^{4} \equiv 1 \pmod{17} \Leftrightarrow  (a^2-1)(a^2+1) \equiv 0 \pmod{17}\\ \Leftrightarrow  (a^2-1)(a^2-16) \equiv 0 \pmod{17}\\ \Leftrightarrow  (a-1)(a+1)(a-4)(a+4) \equiv 0 \pmod{17}$$

Comment: I also thought the solution was more complicated than necessary.

Comment: @N.S.I don't understand how you got that $x^{60} = \begin{cases}1&\text{ if }p\nmid x\\ 0 &\text{ if } p\mid x \end{cases}$. Also, is $x$ a general term or something?

Comment: @fordjones $60=(p-1)\cdot k$ since $p-1 |60$. Then $x^{60}=(x^{p-1})^k$ and use the fact that by FLT either $x=0 \pmod{p}$ or $x^{p-1}=1 \pmod{p}$.

Comment: For each $a\in\{1,2,3,...,16\} \mod 17$, why is the function $f : x \to ax$ a permutation of the numbers $1,2,3,...,33\mod 17$. Also, I don't get how you deduced that $S=a^{60}S\mod 17$ from that claim.

Comment: @fordjones Because $a$ is invertible. It follows immediatelly that $f$ is one to one and onto. As for the second part, use the fact that $\{ a,2a,.., 16a \} = \{1,2,.., 16\}$ because $f$ is a permutation modulo 17.

Answer (score 1):

1) The claim that the set $S^n$ is either $S$ or $\{1\}$ is false.  Take $p = 7$, $S = \{1,2,3,4,5,6\}$ (each element is the least positive representative in their [residue classes](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Modular_arithmetic#Congruence_classes) modulo $p$), and $n = 2$.  According to the claim, since $6 \not\mid 2$, $S^2 = S$.  We compute $$  S^2 = \{1,4,2,2,4,1\} = \{1,2,4\} \neq S  \text{.}  $$  The argument that the powers permute the elements of $S$ could only be true if *every* nonzero residue modulo $p$ were a [primitive root](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Primitive_root_modulo_n) modulo $p$, which is wildly false.

2) This has some hope of being true.  I'd start with [Faulhaber's formula](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Faulhaber%27s_formula) and see where that took me.

3) Notice that $T_{k,n}$ is a sum of powers of residues modulo $p$, so the first $p-1$ terms are a copy of $\Sigma_n$, the next term is a power of a representative from the zero residue class, and then we start over.  This means each block of $p$ terms is $\Sigma_n + 0$.  By the [division algorithm](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Division_algorithm), there are $q$ blocks followed by $r$ remaining residue powers (starting with a representative of the residue class containing $1$).

Comment: @EricTowersgood explanation for 3), but I was wondering why the cases depend on whether $(p-1)\mid n$. Also, as for 2), can you elaborate more on how I can use Faulhaber's formula to know why this is true? Remember, I already have access to the solution, even if some parts are wrong, so there' s no point in posting a solution to this problem; the whole reason why I asked this question in the first place was to *understand*  the solution.

Comment: @fordjones : Every piecewise claim follows from the first wrong one.  The second item depends on whether $p-1$ divides $n$ because the first claim does so.  You seem to have a solution that starts with a wrong claim and then makes every subsequent claim depend intimately on that wrong claim; so there's not much here to understand.